# Trying to make HttpTrigger pass a blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to make a HTTP Trigger in Visual Studio Code which just need to make a file and pass it to blob storage, but I get an error saying: `"The type or namespace 'Blob' could not be found"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example. I think you are just missing a using / referece a nuget package.

Reference Nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

namespace SampleFunctions
{
    public static class Http2BlobFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("Http2BlobFunction")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            [Blob("myblobcontainer/{rand-guid}.txt", FileAccess.Write)] CloudBlockBlob blob,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Received file upload request");
            var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            await blob.UploadTextAsync(requestBody);
            return new OkObjectResult(blob.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you VS Code to develop Azure Function V2.0, you need to manually install package vai .NET.CLI. Since you use storage binding, please run the command `dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage --version 3.0.7` to install the package. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#packages---functions-2x).

Comment: @Recusiwe Do you have any other concern?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the azure CLI to install extensions.

```
func extensions install
```

Finally, you can [use the portal](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions)